# How to force Gmail to send immediately when Undo Send is enabled?

Tags: gmail

As a Gmail user, I find the Undo Send feature very valuable.  I have it set for 30 seconds and regularly take advantage of it to improve an email after I first decided to send it.  However, one disadvantage of the feature is that it adds an extra 30 seconds of waiting before the email will actually be delivered.

Occasionally I want an email to be sent immediately and delivered ASAP - for example if I'm on the phone with someone waiting for it.  I don't need to the option to undo it.  I don't want to go through the settings to disable the feature, then send the email, then go back to the settings and enable it again.

How can I force a single email to be sent ASAP?

I tried closing the "Undo" box after sending it and I tried viewing the message.  In both cases there was no way left I could find in the UI to trigger the Undo any more, but in testing it still didn't trigger the message to deliver any faster.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there's no way to send it immediately if you have undo send enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Your sent email sits in the queue with all others and you can't expedite that.